# Custom TreeView control with a docked ToolStrip doesn't offset nodes properly

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to create a custom TreeView control with a docked ToolStrip, which will contain 4 buttons (Add / Remove Root, Add / Remove Child).

My control looks like this:

```
public partial class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ToolStrip ts = new ToolStrip();
        ts.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        //Repeat this 4x for Add Parent / Delete Parent + Add Child / Delete Child
        ToolStripMenuItem tsmi1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        //Configure DisplayStyle, Image, Text, Name, ClickEvent

        ToolStripSeparator tss = new ToolStripSeparator();

        ts.Items.Add(tsmi1);
        ts.Items.Add(tsmi2);
        ts.Items.Add(tss);
        ts.Items.Add(tsmi3);
        ts.Items.Add(tsmi4);

        ts.Parent = this;

        this.Width = ts.Width + 10;
    }

    void tsmi1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add a root node and N child nodes
    }
}
```

I've dropped an instance of `MyTreeView` on the main form but when I click `tsmi1` it creates the parent & child nodes underneath `Toolstrip ts` so you cannot see them.

I've tried `BringToFront()` on both `this` and `ts`, but it behaves the same either way.

This seems to be a somewhat common question here on SO but the go-to answers aren't working in my case.

Also, dumb question but why is it that when I switch to the Design View for a custom control, which inherits from another control, I cannot see a designer for it? I just get the gray screen that says

> To add components to your class, drag them from the Toolbox and use the Properties window to set their properties. To create methods and events for your class, click here to switch to the code view.

I was expecting just a blank Treeview control I could customize in a designer rather than programatically creating all these child controls to place on it.

Comment: You will have to place the TreeView and the ToolStrip inside a UserControl if you want to make that work.  The TreeView control is not a Container, but you are treating it as one.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, inheriting from `UserControl` instead and then calling `MyCustomTreeViewControl.theTreeViewInstance.BringToFront()` worked.